# Copy a Django model instance including all its relations

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x, copy

i'm playing with django and python3 with a simple blog after start my project.

The thing is. I have a model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
  post_text = models.TextField()
  post_likes = models.BigIntegerField()
  post_author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Comments(models.Model):
  post = models.ForeignKey("Post")
  comment= models.TextField(max_length=100)
```

and i need to make a copy from this two elements in my views. I was using this code.

```
def duplicate(request):
    post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
    post = Post.objects.get(id = post_id)
    new_post = deepcopy(post)
    post.id = None 
    post.save()
    response_data = {}   
    return HttpResponse(
       json.dumps(response_data),
       content_type="application/json"
    )
```

The javascript.

```
$(function() {
 function create_post() {
console.log("create post is working!") // sanity check
$.ajax({
    url : "add_post/",
    type : "POST",
    data : { post_text: $('#text_area').val()},
    success : function(json) {
        $('#text_area').val(''); // remove the value from the input
        console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console       
        $("#posts").append("<tr><td class='card'>"+json.id+"</td><td>"+json.author+"</td><td>"+json.text+"</td><td class='remove-post-button'><button>Borrar</button></td><td class='duplicar'><button onClick='window.location.reload()'>Duplicar</button></td>");            
        console.log("success"); // another sanity check
    },
    // handle a non-successful response
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
            " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>");
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

But it only make a copy from my class "Post" with all the attributes.

My view is.

```
<tbody id='posts'>
{% for post in posts %}
    <tr class="post-card" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">
    <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
    <td class="post-author">{{ post.post_author }}</td>
    <td class="post-content">{{ post.post_text }}</td>
    {% for comment post.comments_set.all %}
    <td class="post-comments">{{comment.comments}}</td>
    {%endfor%}
    <td class="remove-post-button"><button>Borrar</button></td>
    <td class="duplicar"><button onClick='window.location.reload()'>Duplicar</button></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How can i make a copy from Post and Comments and display it in the view?

Answer (score 0):

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances):

> This process does not copy related objects. If you want to copy relations, you have to write a little bit more code.

But be carefull because the example given in Django docs works for a `ManyToMany` field. Here you have a `ForeignKey`, so you'll have to do:

```
def duplicate(request):
    post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    old_comments = post.comment_set.all()
    # copy Post instance
    new_post = post
    post.pk = None 
    post.save()
    # and now we copy all comments
    [post.comment_set.add(comment) for comment in old_comments]
    response_data = {}   
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```